# pip install -e not capturing changes in source code

Tags: python, pip

I have cloned a repository with git and I want to try some changes in the source code. For that, I am creating an environment with `virtualenv` and running `pip install -e .` (where `.` is the directory in the source code that contains the `setup.py`) to install the package in *editable* form.

**Problem:** changes I make to the source code are not captured when I run the package (after activating the environment).

*Insight:* Even if the `site-packages` directory corresponding to the environment contains a `.egg-link` file with a link to the source code, I have realized that it contains a "static" copy of the source code. If I modify the code in that copy, the changes are reflected when I run the code.

Do you know what may be happening? Is this the normal behaviour? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't know why there is a copy of the source code in your site-packages but it is not what you want to have. There should only be links in site-packages, such as my-package.egg-link.

Comment: I would check if the non-editable packages are listed as requirements somewhere, maybe in the setup.py file(s).

Comment: I agree with Olli, this is not normal, paste the setup.py if you can (and if it is not too hairy).

Comment: As the `setup.py` is too long to paste here, let me give you the link to it: https://github.com/stepan-tsirkin/irrep/blob/master/setup.py

Comment: Make sure to uninstall it (you might need to run the uninstall command multiple times) then re-install (as editable, obviously). Or recreate the virtual environment from scratch. You might want to regularly check the output of `pip list`, this will tell you what is installed as editable or not.

Comment: I have checked the output of `pip list`. The package of the source code appears as editable and its path is given. The rest of packages (numpy, scipy,...) are installed as non-editable. I do not see anything strange about this output.